# How to dynamically load custom class from string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails app, where users need to upload their implementations of a Ruby class with definite interface.

What is the best (security/performance) way to instantiate such classes from a pure text in database and use them in my ruby code?

Comment: there's probably no way to securely allow users to write and execute application code directly. See my [tickers](http://github.com/maxpleaner/tickers) project which might be of interest if your app is internal use only. This project has a web interface for writing and executing custom Ruby code. It will run the code in a background job and use websockets to push realtime updates to connected clients.

Comment: "You're entering a world of pain" - Walter Sobchak

Comment: Have also a look at the the safe mode,  http://www.phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/taint.html